# Angular create material toolbar with searchbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

i'm trying to create a toolbar which includes a icon. After this icon was clicked it should open a searchbar please find both screenshots attached:

[image: normal state]

[image: after search was clicked]

The website i have found this nice animation was https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

I tried already to setup a normal toolbar and simply include a input but it didnt work.

So here is the code i have tried:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary"  >
 <mat-toolbar-row>
  <span>
     <img class="logo" src="../assets/eatsmarticon.png">
  </span>
 <span>
  <p class="toolbarname"> L O C A T I O N S</p>
 </span>
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
<span class="example-spacer"></span>
<a routerLink="locations">
   <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example heart icon">filter</mat-icon>
</a>
</mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: easier to help if you share a minimal stackblitz of what you had already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure for add a material icon is `<mat-icon class="material-icons">filter</mat-icon>` so be sure that you already have imported the angular material library to your app and the MatIconModule to app.module.ts